# Android Development: Changing Activity in SurfaceView causes crash

Tags: java, android, android-activity, surfaceview

I made a little Game with the Android SDK. While the main activity was the GameActivity class everything was working fine. But after I made a menu, which is the main activity now it crashes. In the MenuActivity I create a SurfaceView which draws an image with canvas. In the onTouchEvent() I want to change the Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), GameActivity.class);
((Activity) getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```

But when I click on it the screen goes black and after a while the app doesn't resond and needs to be closed.
But apparently it loads the GameActivity and its view(it prints out the String with sysout).
I hope thats enough information.

PS: I'm german, so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Have you added the new Activity to the AndroidManifest.xml? If yes, please attach the error output from logcat.

Comment: Yes I added it to the AndroidManifest.xml. There is no Error in logcat.

Comment: When your app crashes, the logcat will show something for sure.

Comment: I just checked again. There is no error. The app doesn't respond, like it is in a loop. I can choose to wait or close the app, but there is no error

Comment: Oh you wrote crash. If the doesn't respond dialog is shown, then you've must entered an infinite loop like you've said. If you debug your app, does your gameactivity's oncreate / onresume / onstart run?

Comment: I guess it runs the onCreate method. I called System.out.println("test1"); after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in GameActivity. Also in the GameView's surfaceCreated method I call System.out.println("test2");. Both are printed out in logcat.

Comment: Then something in Gameactivity is not responding. If you didn't change anything in GameActivity, unfortunatly I can't help without seeing the code. Once i had infinite loop because of layout xml's but i think that's not the case here.

Comment: Hmmm I don't know why, but suddenly canvas in the gameloop is null. canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(); this must be returning null, but why...

Comment: I didn't get it to work with SurfaceView... so I used just an Activity with a xml file. This works fine now. Anyway thanks for your help.